# How to show 0 if formula is not complete in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using  the formula `=SUM('7-10'!F12+'8-10'!J12-'8-10'!F12)`

This is to work out average daily sales in 24 hours.
But if no sale is recorded for 7-10!f12 but sales are recorded for 8-10!f12 it shows as - (what ever sales there were).

I would like this to show 0 unless there is data in all fields in the formula.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of IF and AND to achieve this.

`=IF(AND(A1>0,B1>0,C1>0),SUM(A1+B1+C1),0)`

See below as to how this works:

[image: Example image 1]

[image: Example image 2]

Comment: If you ever expect negative values to be in a cell, you can use `A1<>0` to basically say; "value must not be 0".

Comment: Or use `=IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>"",C1<>""), SUM(A1+B1+C1), 0)` if one or more of the sales might actually, legitimately be `0` (e.g., if the salesman is out sick, or the state is shut down by a blizzard) but you want to show a result of 0 if the input data are *incomplete* (i.e., at least one is *blank*).